# Instancias de un objeto

Tags: java, poo

Buen día. Tengo una duda respecto a lo que sucede en tiempo de ejecución con la instancia de más de una vez de un objeto.
Es decir...
La primera vez que es instanciado el objeto, comprendo que se crea dicho objeto.
Sin embargo, cuando se manda instanciar nuevamente ¿Se sobreescriben los valores de dicho objeto? o efectivamente ¿Se crea un nuevo objeto? y de ser así que pasa con el objeto creado anteriormente.

Anexo ejemplo de código donde estoy creando varios clientes...

```
System.out.println(" Menu Clientes ");
         System.out.println("1. Crear Cliente");
         System.out.println("2. Crear Cliente Preferente");
         System.out.println("3. Listar Clientes");
         System.out.println("0. Salir");
         System.out.print("\n Selecciones una opcion: ");
         opc= teclado.nextInt();
         switch(opc){
             case 1: System.out.println("1. Crear Cliente ");
                     Cliente c = new Cliente();
                     System.out.print("NIF: ");
                     c.setNif(teclado.next());
                     System.out.print("N° Cuenta: ");
                     c.setnCuenta(teclado.next());
                     System.out.print("Saldo:");
                     c.setSaldo(teclado.nextDouble());
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a qué pasaría si al objeto `c`, una vez creado con `new Cliente()`, y asignado valores con los correspondientes `setxxx()`, le asignaras otro objeto volviendo a hacer `c = new Cliente()`, efectivamente estás creando un objeto nuevo de la clase `Cliente` y asignándoselo a la variable `c`, con lo que lo que tuviera `c` lo pierdes. La máquina virtual de java se encargará de liberar la memoria del objeto inicial.

De la misma manera que si en una función o bloque creas un objeto de cualquier clase y el bloque o función termina. ¿Qué pasa con ese objeto? Pues que se destruye y se pierde.

Si quieres que un objeto concreto sea persistente en la vida de tu programa, tienes que preocuparte de guardar una referencia a él, en algún sitio y que no pierda el ámbito mientras lo necesitas, o se destruirá.

Puedes hacer cosas como:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Cliente c = new Cliente();
    c.setXXXX(lo_que_sea);
    c.setYYYY(cualquier_cosa);
    ProcesadorDeClientes.procesar( c);
}
```

En cada vuelta del bucle crear un objeto, lo rellenas, se lo pasas a otro objeto para que haga algo con él, y vuelves a iterar. Creando otro objeto, etc, etc. Los objetos se crean y se destruyen. En cada vuelta del bucle, la función `procesar` de `ProcesadorDeClientes` podría guardar el objeto en un vector, por ejemplo (me lo estoy inventando sobre la marcha), y entonces ese objeto se mantendría. En la siguiente iteración del bucle se crearía otro en `c`, pero, el primero tendría vida en el vector, mientras `ProcesardorDeClientes` tenga vida.

Todo depende de tus necesidades y tu diseño.

Comment: Cuando la función finalice, lo único que se liberará es la información que esté en la pila (como los parámetros, dirección de retorno, variables locales, esto incluye los punteros que hagan referencia a objetos), es decir, si un objeto fue creado adentro de la función, no se liberará al instante, debido a que, eso se encarga el recolector de basura y lo puede liberar en cualquier momento.

Comment: Vale, sí, pero lo que me parece que preguntaba es qué pasa con los objetos desde el punto de vista del propio programa, y para esos dejan de ser accesibles. Se liberarán cuando se tengan que liberar. Y no depende de su propio programa

Answer (score 0):

Cada objeto creado se almacena de manera volátil dentro de la memoria, en la correspondiente variable, pero no puedes definir dos veces una misma instancia de una clase

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente(argumentos);
Cliente cliente = new Cliente(argumentos); //Este segundo te marcará un error
```

Pero si usar `setVariable(variable)` para cambiar el valor de una variable de la instancia cuantas veces quieras.

En el caso de instanciarse de nuevo, la variable antigua se elimina de la memoria, por lo mismo cada vez que cierras tu programa, todas las variables mueren y desaparecen de la memoria

---

Si se quisiera guardar varios elementos de un mismo tipo sin especificar el nombre de la instancia, `Cliente` en este caso, se podría crear un `ArrayList` de tipo `Cliente`, pero este tipo de dato también es volátil, es decir, toda la información se destruye, cuando termina el programa:

```
ArrayList<Cliente> alCliente = new ArrayList<>();
```

Dentro de lo anterior se pueden guardar objetos enteros de tipo `Cliente`

```
alCliente.add(new Cliente(argumentos)); //no es necesario especificar el nombre de la instancia
```

---

Para poder guardar los datos que haz creado **permanentemente**, la mejor opción es optar por un mantenedor externo, como lo es una base de datos, en ella puedes guardar toda la información que haz creado y consultarla cuando quieras, y esta no tendrá modificaciones.

Te dejo un par de tutoriales en español, de como usar MySQL con Java, así podrás guardar permanentemente todos los datos que quieras:

[Tutorial básico de bases de datos en Java mediante JDBC](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2011/02/25/tutorial-basico-jdbc/)

[TUTORIAL JDBC CON APLICACIONES DE EJEMPLO](https://programandoointentandolo.com/2013/09/tutorial-jdbc-con-aplicaciones-de-ejemplo.html)